# Interpret EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash logs related to SwiftUI

Tags: swift, crash, swiftui

So i'm getting a recurring crash in my app, when the debugger is attached it just jumps to the first line of AppDelegate when it crashes so it doesn't give me much by way of pointing to where something is going wrong.

I have crash logs but i'm not sure how to interpret them, they don't point to any of the lines of code that i've written, they just reference SwiftUI, RenderBox, CoreFoundation, etc. Can anyone help me interpret this or give ideas or share similar experiences that might help?

I have tried several of the diagnostic tools available through Xcode (Address sanitizer, zombies, etc) but I don't want to rule any of those out as maybe I didn't configure them properly or something. Any advice would be welcome, have almost rewritten the whole app trying different things to get rid of this crash but I'm always just guessing.

This is from one of the crash logs:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016f9cfff0
VM Region Info: 0x16f9cfff0 is in 0x16f9cc000-0x16f9d0000;  bytes after start: 16368  bytes before end: 15
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_TINY            000000013a800000-000000013a900000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
      GAP OF 0x350cc000 BYTES
--->  STACK GUARD            000000016f9cc000-000000016f9d0000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  ... for thread 0
      Stack                  000000016f9d0000-000000016facc000 [ 1008K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 0

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [29449]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   RenderBox                       0x00000001d4a27518 RB::Rect::move+ 9496 (RB::AffineTransform&, RB::AffineTransform const&) + 152
1   RenderBox                       0x00000001d4a27504 RB::Rect::move+ 9476 (RB::AffineTransform&, RB::AffineTransform const&) + 132
2   RenderBox                       0x00000001d4a59078 RB::DisplayList::crop_bounds+ 213112 () + 144
3   RenderBox                       0x00000001d4a5a02c RB::DisplayList::draw+ 217132 (RB::DisplayList::Item const*, RB::DisplayList::CachedTransform const&) + 36
4   RenderBox                       0x00000001d4a59f00 RB::DisplayList::draw+ 216832 (RB::DisplayList const&) + 300
5   SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9da5d50 closure #1 in RBGraphicsContext.makeDisplayList+ 2981200 (contentRect:body:) + 152
6   SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9d808a0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext) -> + 2828448 (@unowned Bool) + 40
7   SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9d805f4 closure #1 in cachedGraphicsRenderer+ 2827764 (_:) + 184
8   SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
9   SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
10  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
11  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
12  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
13  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
14  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
15  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
16  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
17  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
18  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
19  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
20  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
21  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
22  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
23  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
24  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
25  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
26  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
27  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
28  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
29  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db6654 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed GraphicsContext, @in_guaranteed CGSize) -> (@out + 3049044 ()) + 64
30  SwiftUI                         0x00000001d9db71f0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed GraphicsContext, @unowned CGSize) -> + 3052016 () + 44
```

The SwiftUI lines continue with the same type of thing all the way up to 510, I cut it off at 30 due to question size limit. The fact that there are like 500 of almost the same thing from SwiftUI repeating seems bad, but I don't know enough to say one way or the other in this case.

Comment: i think without your code we can just guess....a hint: comment out your code until it runs, then comment in little pieces until it crashes again -> in most cases theses lines include the error

Comment: Find a code that generate this. Yes, sometimes in SwiftUI it is not obvious - I would exclude views one-by-one in affected workflow till originator found.

Comment: I've done a lot of commenting out of views and functionality and am unable to track it down to any particular place in the code. I'm not asking for what is wrong, and more asking for help using the info Xcode is giving me to go in the right direction. There has to be some way to use the crash log info to determine some kind of info about what is wrong.

Comment: So I did figure out that it only crashes after updating the UI a large number of times. I believe it to be a bug in SwiftUI but it is hard to say for sure. As a workaround i'm using the .id modifier to change the id of the view and swap it out with a new one every so often so that it does not reach the amount of updates that is resulting in a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this ended up just being bugs on Apple's side in SwiftUI. I submitted feedback reports and they eventually got fixed in later versions of iOS without me making any changes to my code.

I don't think there was anything that I could have done myself to track down the crashes and resolve them since they were issues in the framework itself.